# Visual Studio 2013 preview and Windows Azure projects compatibility

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013

After installing the new Visual Studio I tried to open my solution which contained the Windows Azure project (Cloud Service) with 1 webrole and 1 workerrole. Visual Studio notified me that this project type is not yet supported by this version of IDE. After searching the web I've found the following info:

The Windows Azure SDK for .NET is not compatible with the Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Preview. This means that Visual Studio 2013 **can not yet be used** to author, debug, or publish **cloud service projects**. In addition, no Server Explorer support is available for features other than Mobile Services, and streaming logging is not available for web sites. An SDK release that is compatible with Visual Studio 2013 **will be available later in the summer**.

(C) http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/visual-studio-2013/

So I'm just windering whether there are any workarounds yet to develop Cloud Services in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: The purpose of this site is to provide the community with the most relevant answers. Your answer on the other hand even in June was really useless as I've described the problem in full detail and provided the quote from Microsoft regarding the possible dates. You haven't added any useful information, just confirmed my info and even got some votes for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 preview now **supports** Windows Azure Projects.

**Using Visual Studio 2013 Preview with Windows Azure**

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/visual-studio-2013/

Answer (score 5):

No! There aren't yet ways to develop Azure Cloud Service projects with VS 2013.